# How to store file into network shared folder using laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I want to store excel file to a network shared folder using laravel 5.8. I have read laravel documentation for using filesystem to do this. I have do `symbolic link` using `mklink` to directory `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Generate`. And I have setting permission `read and write` for the `Generate` folder.

This is my filesystem :

```
'trading' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Generate\tradingid',
],
```

This is my function :

```
 public function ($id){
   $data = Excel::store(new ExportData($id), 'ExcelData.xlsx', 'trading');

   if($data){
    echo 'success';
   }else{
    echo 'error';
   }
}
```

For store the excel file i'm using library `Maatwebsite`.

When function executed, i got error response like this 
`"The root path C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Generate\\tradingid is not readable."`.

[image]

How to fix this issue?